# Reserve 2D Vector in C++ and copy data from array

Tags: c++, arrays

I hope to use vector to process the 2d array data obtained by calling a third-party library.

Although I can simply use the loop to assign values one by one, But I prefer to use methods such as insert and copy to deal with this.

I found that reserve doesn't seem to work here. So I used resize instead.

```
double **a = new double *[1024];
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
    a[i] = new double[512];
}

std::vector<std::vector<double>> a_v;
a_v.resize(1024, std::vector<double>(512));

// Copy a -> a_v
```

I made these attempts:

```
// Not Working, just 0 in vector
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i){
    a_v[i].insert(a_v[i].end(), a[i], a[i] + 512);
}
```

Is there any good way to solve this problem.

For a 1D array I write like this:

```
double *b = new double[1024];
std::vector<double> b_v;

b_v.reserve(1024);
b_v.insert(b_v.end(), b, b + 1024);
```

Comment: what is "this problem" ? Is the code not doing what you want it to do? Are the errors?

Comment: What **I** want to do is call `for (auto t : a) a_v.emplace_back(std::move(t));`. Create 1024 new vectors by moving (giving the vector ownership of) the C-style array into the vector. But vector lacks a constructor for that. Note: Since the array comes from a third-party library I wonder if it was `malloc`ed. That would make this even more impossible.

Comment: Are you sure the library returns an array of pointers to arrays of double instead of a single 2D array of doubles? You could cast the doubles to `std:array` if you can live with implementation defined behavior (the cast is IDB).

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) a_v[i].insert(a_v[i].end(), a[i], a[i] + 512);` looks like the most readable version. In the end that also assigns one by one value to the `vector` internally.

Comment: The Library is a C Library and those data are malloc form the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size of the source array is fixed, it is strongly recommended to use `std::array` instead of `std::vector`. `std::array` has continuous memory layout for multidimensional structures, thus `std::memcpy` can be used for copy if the source array is also continuous in memory.

Look back to the original question. If you want to construct a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` from the source array, use a single loop to construct 1D vectors from the source:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> a_v;
a_v.reserve(1024);
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
    a_v.emplace_back(std::vector<double>(&(a[i][0]), &(a[i][512])));
}
```

If there is already a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` with the proper size, and you literally just want to do a copy from the source, use the `assign` member function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
    a_v[i].assign(&(a[i][0]), &(a[i][512]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> a_v;
a_v.resize(1024, std::vector<double>(512));
```

is just

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> a_v{1024, std::vector<double>(512)};
```

Unfortunately there is no vector constructor that takes over ownership of a C-style array. So you have to copy all 1024 * 512 doubles. And with the above definition of the vector you needlessly initialize all the doubles before you overwrite them.

You can do it with reserve so none of the double get initialized before you overwrite them and no vector gets copied or moved:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> a_v;
a_v.reserve(1024);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
    a_v.emplace_back();
    std::vector<double> &b_v = a_v.back();
    b_v.reserve(512);
    b_v.insert(b_v.end(), a[i], a[i] + 512);
}
```

Comment: well, I'm not declaring vector here, it's just an example